# iPhone Only App Xcode 6 GM

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I've been trying for the past hour to create an iPhone only app on Xcode which runs with the 2x and 1x option. However when I run it on my **iPad Mini with Retina Display** its displaying as a full screen app instead. I've tried to set the deployment target devices to just iPhone, and unchecked the "Use Size Classes" as well but it's not working. Is this a Xcode bug or am I missing something?

[image: Size Classes]

[image: Target Device]

Comment: Hi did you find an answer? I stuck on the same thing.

Comment: @aykutt I think it must have been a bug in Xcode 6 GM because eventually I was able to make it iPhone only by changing the "Devices" to iPhone instead of Universal.